# Why does IDEA mark certain parts of Play code red?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm pretty new to the Play framework. I've been trying to configure it so I can use it with IntelliJ Ultimate.

I use following:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 14.03
- Scala plugin for IntelliJ 1.2.1
- Play Framework 2.3.7 (the one that works online 1,2MB)
- Scala 2.11
- JDK 1.7
- Windows 7

My problem is all about the fact that i can't make the errors disappear. Below is a simple example. When I create something more complicated (mapping etc.) I get entire blocks of red (also it does not suggest any code for the more complicated code).

[image]

What I've tried to fix it:
- deleting .idea folder and generating it again
- cleaning sbt
- generating a Play app from inside activator and also from IntelliJ
- re-installing IntelliJ

This is how I create the app from inside IntelliJ

[image]

I'm new both to Scala and Play, but I've done some research and I didn't end up with working solution. The same project works on Eclipse, but I would like to stick with IntelliJ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931644/play-framework-tutorial-cannot-resolve-symbol-index

Comment: @cosmolev Play plugin is not required in IDEA 14. Its now part of the scala plugin.

Comment: @lukasz I found the easiest way was to create using activator and import as an SBT project (not a play project). Have you tried this?

Comment: The Scala plugin 1.2.1 is quite old (given the development stage/pace of the Scala support in IDEA). You should really be using the EAP version 1.2.67.9.EAP following the steps in  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Cassiopeia.

Comment: @LionelPort - i have tried loading from SBT, still i didnt solve the problem

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - thx Jacek - your solution is working.  Now i'm using Scala plugin Ver. 1.2.67.9 EAP.

Comment: Thanks. Approve my answer and then I'm gonna delete the comment above (and flag yours as obsolete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala plugin 1.2.1 is *fairly* outdated (given the development stage/pace of the Scala support in IntelliJ IDEA).

As of today, **Jan, 29th**, you should really be using [the latest version of the Scala plugin 1.3](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/01/29/scala-plugin-1-3-is-available/).

[image: Scala plugin 1.3]