# Cannot resolve symbol 'play' error with Play Framework 2.4.x and IntellijIdea 14.x

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.4

I've created a Play-java [v 2.4.2] project with using activator[v 1.3.5] that uses JDK 1.8 on Windows 64-bit OS. I've run `activator run` command and it works smoothly.

But when I open that project in Intellij Idea [v 14.1.4] IDE not working properly; warns me in controller and view files as follows:
[image: Intellij IDEA 14.x controller]

and this:

[image: Intellij IDEA 14.x view]

And it says: 'Cannot resolve symbol ...'

I googled this and find some useful links, included a few stackoverflow Q&A's, i.e: [Play framework tutorial: Cannot resolve symbol 'index'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931644/play-framework-tutorial-cannot-resolve-symbol-index)

I've Scala and Play plugins and in this path ([File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> [MyAppModule] -> Sources Tab]) there is no "target/scala-[version]/src_managed" directory. Look this:

[image: Intellij IDEA 14.x project structure]

In this Intellij Idea or Play version, something's changed.

I've tried some combinations for making folders as source folder or excluded. I've used IDE's option: 'Invalidate Caches/Restart'. None of them worked for me.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have Scala plugin?

Comment: I've already write that inside my question: 'I've Scala and Play plugins...'

Comment: I get that sometimes - Try right-clicking the project, select "Add Framework Support" and select "Play 2.x" and click OK.

Comment: Did you imported this project as a SBT Project?

Comment: did you performed all steps from this page: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

Comment: This question is duplicated and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063562/cannot-resolve-symbol-routes/34213829#34213829

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution. Here are the steps that I followed:

- Create a play-java project using activator.
- Import that project as an SBT project to Intellij Idea.
- Right click on project then select "Add Framework Support" and then
  select "Play 2.x"
- Build -> make project.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: i using intellij idea 15.0.1 but haven't Play 2.x. i installed scala plugin.

Comment: yes, mine is intellij-idea community edition, and it doesn't have Play Framework in Add Framework Support too... @MHossein, how did you get it to work with Play?

Answer (score 4):

For play project, you have to let Intellij know this is a SBT project.

File -> Open -> select the .sbt file under the root directory of your project. It will take Intellij a while to resolve the project and download dependencies.

In addition, from my personal experience, you should use *activator new* to create a new Play project and import that project into Intellij rather than directly creating a Play project usingn Intellij Play plugin. Sometimes, the plugin does not work properly.